# Uncalled function running when variable is outside, but doesn't run unless called when variable is inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, environment-variables

if you reference configtype inside of configselect() then the function wont run unless called, however when configtype is referenced outside of configselect() then the input() function will run and no values will be returned.

what do yall think is going on here?

```
import os

configtype = int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? "))

def configselect():
    if configtype == 1:
        print("you chose 962")
    elif configtype == 2:
        print("you chose Audience")
    elif configtype == 3:
        print("you chose mAP")
    else:
        print("Try again dummy")
```

Comment: _the function wont run unless called_ This is true of any function.  I'm unsure what your actual question is...

Comment: You always need to call the function `configselect()` for it to run. When you reference configtype outside of the function, the `input()` function will be run as part of the script since it is called

Comment: The `input()` function is always going to run regardless as soon as you run (or import) this file.  Whether or not you reference `configtype` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a function to run, you need to call with its name.

```
import os

configtype = int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? "))

def configselect():
    if configtype == 1:
        print("you chose 962")
    elif configtype == 2:
        print("you chose Audience")
    elif configtype == 3:
        print("you chose mAP")
    else:
        print("Try again dummy")

configselect()
```

The above would run.

Also, generally, you should write the function as

```
def configselect(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print("you chose 962")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("you chose Audience")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("you chose mAP")
    else:
        print("Try again dummy")
```

So that it's more reusable.

Finally, in order for your function to not always print "Try again dummy", you should convert configtype into an integer. Input will always return a string.

Comment: Not only is passing a parameter more reusable, it's just far easier to follow.  Passing information by global variables quickly becomes an unmaintainable rats nest.  Don't ask me how I know.

Comment: if i pass a parameter, how would I allow for user input that functions the same way as the previous code i had so i dont have to use a global variable?

Comment: TypeError: configselect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'choice'

Comment: Well, you have to pass a parameter into the function, like configselect( what you want choice to be ).